# Finding Mutually disjoint subsets of a list with python

Tags: python, list, sage

How do we go about finding all sets of lists consisting of mutually disjoint subsets from a given list. Assuming that the list `L` consists of a list of tuples, I tried the following code, but to no avail:

```
L=[Large list of lists of tuples]
K=[]
for i in L:
      for j in len(L):
                if set(i).intersect(set(L[j]))==Integer(0):
                   K.append(i,L[j])
       list(K)
```

But, I got the error saying that 'int' object is not iterable. I also tried the following, but to no avail:

```
L=[Large list of list of tuples]
K=[]
 for i,j in L:
     if set(i).intersect(set(j))==0:
         K.append(i,j)
 list(K)
```

But, I got the error that there are too many values to unpack. How do we mitigate these problems. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output is - please provide a sample input and a sample output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this Solution using itertools:

```py
import itertools

ls = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
k = []

# for all 2 element combinations of set
for i,j in itertools.combinations(ls,2):
    # an empty set is True, a nonempty set is False
    if not set(i).intersection(set(j)):
        k.append((i,j))
    
print(k)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. But, I have two queries:1) Is there a way to do the same thing (although less efficiently) without using `itertools`.2) Is there a way to list all subsets which are pairwise disjoint, like if `L=[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1],[2]]`, I want the output to be:`X=[([1,2],[3,4]),([1,3],[2,4]),([1,4],[2,3]),([1,2,3]),(2,3,4]),([1],[2,3,4]),([1],[2,3]),([1],[3,4]),([1],[2,3]),...]`

Comment: contd... `[...([1],[2,4]),([2],[1,3]),([2],[1,4]),([2],[3,4]),([1],[2],[3,4])]`. Please ignore the repeating elements

Comment: 1) itertools is a standard packacke, but you can use the Equivalent as described in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations .